# Need to filter the data on the basis of two column having many to one relationship using awk

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, gawk, mawk

I have a big file having 50s columns and 100K of rows delimited by |. Now $2(col 2) has multiple type of $1(col 1) value which means col 2 will be repeated. So I have sorted the file. I need now to extract/filter the result file on the basis of below condition:
$1 is column 1
$2 is column 2

there is one to many relation ship between $2 and $1

> condition 1 : when $2 has both type of $1 (value of $1 for $2 is more
>   than 8000 as well as less than 8000) then select the complete row
>   where  $1 < 8000 for the given $2(column 2)
>
> condition 2: if $2 has only $1 >= 8000 then select the complete row
>   where $1 is the smallest for the given $2(column 2) E.g: source file
>    In the below example we have 3 types of $2 (1234,123 & 456) Now 1234 has 3 types of value in column 1 ($1) means greater as well as less than 8000. So we have selected the complete row for those having $1<8000.

For 123 and 465 we have value of column 1 only greater than 8000($1>80000) so we have selected the row which is latest (on the basis of higher the value of column 8) .

Sample File

```
  4000|1234||||||23
    5000|1234||||||40
    9000|1234||||||25
    10000|123|||||||21
    9000|123|||||||22
    22000|456|||||||27
    15000|456|||||||29
```

result file would have:

```
4000|1234||||||23
5000|1234||||||40

9000|123|||||||22

15000|456|||||||29
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your best attempt and the problem you faced.

Comment: i am struggling with arrays. Please advice for the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try (u being your file)

```
sort -n -t\| -k2 -k1 < u |
awk -F\| '$1 < 8000 { a[$2]++ ; print } 
          $1 >= 8000 { if ( !a[$2] && ( !e[$2] || e[$2]<$8 ))  {u[$2]=$0;e[$2]=$8;} ; } 
          END { for ( i in u ) print u[i] ;}'
```

gives

```
4000|1234||||||23
5000|1234||||||40
15000|456||||||29
9000|123||||||22
```

where

- `-t\|` and `-F\|` instruct sort and awk to use `|` as separator
- `-k2` `-k1` : sort by second, then fist field
- `|` in sort line should be last char in line
- `$1 < 8000 { a[$2]++ ; print }` if under 8000, print lines and remember $2 value
- `$1 >= 8000 { ... }` if above, store highest value
- `END { for ( i in u ) print u[i] ;}` upon exiting, dump all value
- you may need to re-sort.
- line 2 condition could be simplified (by having if's condition outside {} )
- some line in your test have 9 field.

note that command can be one lined

```
... | sort -n -t\| -k2 -k1  | awk -F\| '...'
```

Comment: Thanks Archemar....!! condition 1 is running fine but condition 2.                  In condition 2:  we need to  fetch that row which is having maximum $8 value.

Comment: +1.  BTW, ending a line with `|` isn't a bashism - it works in every shell i've tried it in (zsh, dash, ksh, busybox sh, and bash).   Also, `|` doesn't have to be the last character on a line, it only has to be the last non- [[:blank:]] character on a line, any number of whitespace chars can follow it.

Comment: Great!!!Archemar, Just one more advice!! if i need to print  if $2 has only $1 >= 8000 then select only those rows having maximum value of $8.(modified condition 2)

Comment: @api1411 ... then remove first awk line and ref to a[$2].